# How can i get id from a while loop when change a select box in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list of order items in a `table` and I show them using a `while` loop. Inside each row I have a `select` which I am trying to update the order item status from an order item id. I need to get the order item id each time when I change the dropdown so that I send it to another page in AJAX.

```
while($orderItemData = $orderItemResult->fetch_array()) 
{
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left:20px;">
      <div class="form-group">    
        <p><?php echo $orderItemData['product']; ?></p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left:20px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <p><?php echo $orderItemData['quantity']; ?></p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php $order_item_id = $orderItemData['order_item_id']; ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="pick_status" id="pick_status" data-id="<?php echo $order_item_id; ?>">
      <select class="form-control" name="status" onchange="updatestatus(this.value)">
        <option value="1">Pending</option>
        <option value="2">Picked</option>
      </select>         
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

```js
function updatestatus(val) {
  var status = val;
  var orderid = $('#pick_status').attr("data-id")
  alert(orderid);
}
```

It gets me only the first row id when I change the dropdown. How can I get each row id when I change the dropdown?

Comment: `id` attribute should be unique in a sinlge `dom` . Try with `class` and `var orderid = $(this).parent().parent().find('className').attr("data-id")`

Answer (score 0):

Just make these changes in your code and use jquery.

```
<select class="form-control status" id="<?php echo $order_item_id; ?>">
    <option value="1">Pending</option>
    <option value="2">Picked</option>
</select>
```

In JQuery

```
$(".status").on('change',function()
{
  var orderid=$(this).attr(id);
//ajax code
});
```

Comment: <select class="form-control status" id="<?php echo $order_item_id; ?>"> id or data-id

Comment: use id as id is containing the order id.